# Heketi can't provision a volume for Heketi database

Tags: glusterfs

I'm trying to make glusterfs cluster with Heketi for Kubernetes persistent volumes. I have 3 nodes in gluster cluster:

```
heketi-cli node list
    Id:242e801e6eeb7ec10acda60a409b5d98     Cluster:fd539c5d13b6229498c6c67ac491163d
    Id:439fb090888a745633f9db6ac4d243b8     Cluster:fd539c5d13b6229498c6c67ac491163d
    Id:5e9b7e5f3ec33c77c42437e89ca857a3     Cluster:fd539c5d13b6229498c6c67ac491163d
```

But when I try to provision a volume for Heketi database by using command:

```
heketi-cli setup-openshift-heketi-storage
```

I get an error:

```
Error: No space
```

But I have enough free space on my volumes:

```
Devices:
Id:931b4f87e3675368a4f737ed6862e0cf   Name:/dev/sdb            State:online    Size (GiB):29      Used (GiB):0       Free (GiB):29
Devices:
Id:3a2a30b22ade4efca7949e9cc082b685   Name:/dev/sdb            State:online    Size (GiB):29      Used (GiB):0       Free (GiB):29
Devices:
Id:5d1b5c7b258c52569bff1e1c720015c5   Name:/dev/sdb            State:online    Size (GiB):29      Used (GiB):0       Free (GiB):29
```

What can be the reason for this strange behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I have found the reason. It's the count of gluster node, it should be equal to count of gluster instances in kubernetes. In previous turn I had only 3 gluster nodes and 4 gluster instances in kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a number of problems that lead to this error message. The 2 most common ones are:

- You do not have the minimum of 3 nodes in your gluster cluster
- The `heketi-cli setup-openshift-heketi-storage` command needs to create a volume for heketi's database. That volume is now 2GB by default but it used to 32GB(!) (see [heketi issue #639](https://github.com/heketi/heketi/issues/639)). So depending on your heketi-cli version it may be trying to create a 32GB volume on your 29GB bricks. Nasty.

I suggest you look at the logs of heketi:

```
$ kubectl get pod -l name=heketi
NAME                     READY     STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
heketi-703226055-7g3hb   1/1       Running       0          18h

$ kubectl logs heketi-703226055-7g3hb -f
Heketi v3.0.0-111-gc5f0f58
[heketi] INFO 2017/02/14 22:17:53 Loaded kubernetes executor
...
```